# How to run a script with a different version of Python

Tags: python

I just start learning Python in my company, I usually type `python ext.py` to run a script. The default Python version is 2.4. But now I need to run a new script in Python 3.

The company's IT support installed Python 3 in `/usr/local/python3.2.3/bin/python3`, but when I type `python -V` to check version, it still shows Python 2.4. The IT support said they can't replace the old version. How can i run the script using Python 3?

Comment: You just need to provide the absolute path to the python interpreter. When you type "python -v" it is finding the default version, or the first version it finds based on your PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/local/python3.2.3/bin/python3 -V`
`/usr/local/python3.2.3/bin/python3 ext.py`

Answer (score 3):

You can modify your PATH environment variable to get python3 picked up first, or create an alias that'll give you a command for running python3.

To modify your PATH edit your shell configuration file (e.g., ~/.bashrc if you are using BASH)

PATH=/usr/local/python3.2.3/bin:$PATH

To create an alias to python3 do (in the same file),

alias python3=/usr/local/python3.2.3/bin/python3

Answer (score 0):

As py2 and 3 have so many differences, usually Python 3 will be started with `python3` instead of a mere `python`.